# Java Futures & Fast Dot Product

Tags: java, matrix, vector, concurrency

I'm trying to implement a dot product that leverages concurrency to run faster. I'm going for a divide and conquer approach where I split the vector into smaller and smaller bits then finally sum all the components together. But, instead of returning the values right away, I return `Future`s that will eventually contain the results.

Here's my attempt so far:

```
Future<Double> dotProduct(double[] x, double[] d, int start, int end) {
    if ((end-start) == 1) {
      return executor.submit(() -> {
        return x[start] * d[start];
      });
    } else if ((end-start) == 0) {
      return executor.submit(() -> {
        return 0.0;
      });
    }

    int middle = (start+end)/2;
    Future<Double> leftDotProduct = dotProduct(x, d, start, middle);
    Future<Double> rightDotProduct = dotProduct(x, d, middle, end);

    return executor.submit(() -> {
      double l = leftDotProduct.get();
      double r = rightDotProduct.get();
      return l + r;
    });
  }

  // Usage:
  Future<Double> v = dotProduct(x, d, 0, x.length);
  v.get()
```

It produces correct results but it still runs slower than the equivalent sequential implementation. I've tested on small (4 entries) and large (20,000) entries.

I was thinking the slow down might be due to the recursive calls and setting up new stacks. But I'm not even sure how to redesign the algo if that was the case.

Any thoughts on what could be causing the delay and how to improve it would be really appreciated!

---

Edit:

For more context, I want to return futures because ultimately I aim to use this method to multiply a matrix by a vector:

```
  double[] parMult(double[] x) {
    if (this.getWidth() != x.length)
      throw new ArithmeticException("The matrix and vector are of incompatible sizes");

    // Create an array of futures that will store all the results from dot poduct
    Future<Double>[] f = new Future[this.getHeight()];
    for (int i=0; i<this.getHeight(); i++) {
      f[i] = dotProduct(x, this.data[i]);
    }

    // Get the values of all futures
    double[] b = new double[this.getHeight()];
    try {
      for (int i = 0; i < this.getHeight(); i++) {
        b[i] = f[i].get();
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return b;
  }
```

Comment: Generally there's no value in splitting this kind of workload up into more pieces than you have (hyper-)cores.  Anything further is just adding overhead.

Comment: Maybe of interest to you: http://richardstartin.uk/targeting-simd-in-java/

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth - makes sense. I hoped that limiting my thread pool to just 4 threads might give modest improvements but it's much worse (ave sequential: 16ms, ave concurrent: 8399ms)

Comment: 20k is totally insufficient to parallelize. When you get into the high 100's and into the millions then you will see improvement. I maintain a Data Parallel product that does matrix and vector processing if you would like to see how I do it: https://sourceforge.net/projects/tymeacdse/

Answer (score 2):

When you call `Future.get()` you wait for the future to complete. So, what just happened is you introduced all the overhead of an executor with numerous tasks to dispatch *and* you forced your code to run almost serially because you block.

What you are looking for instead is [Fork+Join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html). The cumulative sum of products is a classic example of the fork+join pattern.

Comment: Shouldn't calling the `.get()` method inside my executor thread make it non blocking though? Thanks for the other link - I'll check it out!

Comment: It won't block the thread which calls `submit()`, but note that the only reason you don't deadlock (unless you have an unbounded thread pool) is because you schedule your work 'bottom up'. (If you issued your recursive call to `dotProduct()` inside the submitted task, you'd likely see deadlock).

Comment: What you have effectively done, is dividing your work in stages and then you synchronising for each combining step. Note that there is little need for that synchronisation because: `a + (b + c) == (a + b) + c`. So the waiting with `.get()` is not quite necessary. If you use fork+join instead, you may see a benefit from the work stealing feature so if `b` happens to resolve faster than `a`, the thread working on `b` will start to work on `c` early.

Comment: I suppose the benefit I was trying to go after was `(a+b) + (c+d)` instead of `((a+b)+c)+d)` because in the former I can compute `(a+b) = x` and `(c+d) = y` concurrently then `x+y`. In the latter, I have to do `(a+b) = x` then `x + c = y` then `y + d` all serially.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Java Fork/Join framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) - it is designed exactly for this kind of computations.

> The fork/join framework is an implementation of the ExecutorService interface that helps you take advantage of multiple processors. It is designed for work that can be broken into smaller pieces recursively. The goal is to use all the available processing power to enhance the performance of your application.

For your particular case it could be something like this:

```
class Product extends RecursiveTask<Double> {

    private final double[] x;
    private final double[] d;
    private final int start;
    private final int end;

    Product(double[] x, double[] d, int start, int end) {
        this.x = x;
        this.d = d;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    protected Double compute() {
        if ((end-start) == 1) {
            return x[start] * d[start];
        } else if ((end-start) == 0) {
            return 0.0;
        }
        int middle = (start+end)/2;
        Product leftDotProduct = new Product(x, d, start, middle);
        Product rightDotProduct = new Product(x, d, middle, end);
        return leftDotProduct.fork().join() + rightDotProduct.fork().join();
    }
}
```

Then you can create it and `fork()`, or just call `compute()`

```
Product p = new Product(x, d, 0, 999999);
```

After some tests it seems to be about 3 times faster than your approach, but still much slower than simple recursive solution.

Another option is to use [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html). Let's say you have a recursive method:

```
double dotProduct(double[] x, double[] d, int start, int end) {
    if ((end-start) == 1) {
        return x[start] * d[start];
    } else if ((end-start) == 0) {
        return 0.0;
    }

    int middle = (start+end)/2;
    double leftDotProduct = dotProduct(x, d, start, middle);
    double rightDotProduct = dotProduct(x, d, middle, end);

    return leftDotProduct + rightDotProduct;
}
```

You can create `CompletableFuture` like this:

```
CompletableFuture<Double> f = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> dotProductSingleThread(x, d, 0, 999999));
```

Then, if you have many futures, you can use

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(futures)
```

to wait until al of them are completed.